# Unable to retrieve metadata for xyz.model.xxx in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using entity-framework in mvc. I am receiving this error while generating view.I am using MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using EF. I am Trying to generate a list using scaffold template.

This Entity Framework auto generated class

```
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual TblDepartment TblDepartment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult EmployeesByDep()
{
    var employees = db.Employees.Include("TblDepartment").GroupBy(x => x.TblDepartment.DepName)
        .Select(y => new TotalDepartments
        {
            DepName = y.Key,
            Total = y.Count()

        }
        ).ToList().OrderByDescending(y=>y.Total);
    return View(employees);
}
```

Model Code:

```
public string DepName { get; set; }
public int Total { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Syed What versions of MVC/EF are you using? Was scaffolding working previously in this project? What have you done since it worked? What is the *full* error message?

Comment: DavidG i am using mvc 5 and entityframework v 6

Comment: @DavidG I am facing this when i am trying to generate Scaffold Template List .

Comment: @Nkosi no its not working.

Comment: Try leaving the datacontext empty when scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you had not declared a key.

You should create a new class EmployeeMetaData.cs

With:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
public partial class Employee
{  
}
public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

add: using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`;